# Questions about derivation of dipole electric field at axial and equatorial point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

Firstly, in derivation of electric field at an axial point due to a dipole we have to determine the Electric field at a point P on the axial. So there are two electric fields acting on this $\text{Point P}$, $E\left(-q\right)$ and $E \left(+q\right)$

$$E\left(-q\right)=\dfrac{-q}{4\pi} \qquad \text{and} \qquad E\left(+q\right)=\dfrac{+q}{4\pi} \,,$$
then we do the derivation...

But in equatorial point of a dipole,$$
E\left(-q\right)=\dfrac{+q}{4\pi} \qquad \text{and} \qquad E\left(+q\right)=\dfrac{+q}{4\pi} \, ,$$
but why?  Why electric field is taken $+ve$ in $E\left(-q\right)$ in equatorial point derivation?

Comment: But it's not... Whatever you read probably has a typo.

Comment: Without a diagram it's impossible to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a certain direction has been chosen as positive.
So let's have the +q on the left and the -q on the right and right is positive.

Putting a positive charge between those two charges results in the left positive charge exerting a force to the right (positive) on the positive charge in the middle and the right negative charge is also exerting a force to the right (positive) on the positive charge in the middle.

So to get the net force on the charge in the middle you add two positive forces and get a net force whose direction is to the right.